# How to make Swiper slides autoplay continuously on React, NextJs instead of playing with pause?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I implemented the following Swiper sliders on my react component (on NextJs). It does autoplay but pauses after each slide. I want this to autoplay continuously something like this `(https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-autoplay-shift-6z5jk1)`. Please help me guys if you have found out a solution for this.

```
<Swiper
            spaceBetween={0}
            loop={true}
            centeredSlides={true}
            speed={5000}
            autoplay={{
              delay: 0,
              disableOnInteraction: false,
            }}
            slidesPerView={6}
            modules={[Autoplay]}
            className="mySwiper"
          >
            <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>Slide 7</SwiperSlide>
          </Swiper>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `transition-timing-function` to `linear` in your stylesheets solves your issue.

```css
.swiper-wrapper {
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Or you can do the same thing programmatically:

```js
<Swiper
  ...
  onSwiper={(swiper) => {
    swiper.$wrapperEl[0].style.transitionTimingFunction = "linear";
  }}
```